# How can I update the data fetched from a future bilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

In my app I have a screen which contains 3 different future builders, I would like to update the data recovered from a future builder. I tried the setState () method but this updates all 3 future builders on the page, I only need to update one. How can I do ?

My 3 future builders are structured like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
future: getData(), //Fetch the data
builder:
    (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    return Text('${snapshot.data}',
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Colors.black));
  } else {
    return const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rebuild just a portion of your screen, you can use `StatefulBuilder`.
Wrap the single `FutureBuilder` you want to rebuild with a `StatefulBuilder` like so:

```dart
StatefulBuilder(
 builder: (context, setState) {
  return YourFutureBuilder();
 },
)
```

If `setState` is called from inside the `StatefulBuilder`, only the portion of the screen that is wrapped with the `StatefulBuilder` will be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Setstate will always rebuild your page. please use State management plugins like getx,provider for some portion update.

Comment: "Setstate will always rebuild your page" - This is not true. You do not need state management plugins to rebuild only parts of your screen. They make it more convenient but are not necessarily needed. Anything you can do with a plugin, you can also do without it, it may only require more effort.